# Smallest number of quantum gates to simulate other gates?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-computer

What is the smallest number of Fredkin gates needed to simulate a [Toffoli gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toffoli_gate)? What is the smallest number of Toffoli gates needed to simulate a [Fredkin gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredkin_gate)?

Where the Toffoli's gate is the CCNOT and the Fredkin gate is CSWAP (controlled swap) (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_gate#Commonly_used_gates)

I can create both gates using the other, but I don't know how to prove that I'm using the "smallest" number.
(Of course, using auxiliary lines with 0,1 is mandatory, especially using only the Fredkin gate.)

Answer (score 1):

In both cases the answer is 4 gates.

A solution for this problem can be found in [Andrew Landahl](http://info.phys.unm.edu/~alandahl/)'s [notes](http://info.phys.unm.edu/~alandahl/phys452f07/ps1soln.pdf) for the course *[Physics 452/581: Introduction to Quantum Information](http://info.phys.unm.edu/~alandahl/phys452f07/)*, University of New Mexico. I quote the author's original solution (with some minor corrections).

> In both cases, the minimum number of gates required to simulate the other is 4. A
>   proof of such a minimum requires exhaustively demonstrating that 1, 2 or 3 gates
>   is insufficient to achieve the simulation. Such a proof is omitted here and was not
>   required for credit. Unfortunately, intuition seems to be the best alternative to finding
>   the minimum number of gates and the related circuit.

By ``exhaustively demonstrating'' the author means that you can just write a computer program that lists all possible gates that you can obtain by combining 1, 2 and 3 Toffoli/Fredkin gates, and carefully check that none of them corresponds to the gate that you want to synthesize.

> ### **Fredkin simulates Toffoli**
>
> We first explore some of the features of the Fredkin
>   gate. Generally, we write the gate as
>
> [image]
>
> For particular choices of ancilla, we find
>
> 1. FANOUT/NOT
>
>    [image]
> 2. AND
>
>    [image]
>
> In terms of our desired output, we see that the first two inputs are trivially
>   mapped (aside from any possibly FANOUTs needed). The third output requires combining xy with z:
>
> [image]
>
> Combining these steps gives the following circuit, (with relevant intermediary outputs labeled):
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> ### **Toffoli simulates Fredkin**
>
> We write the Toffoli gate as
>
> [image]
>
> Relevant properties of the Toffoli gate are
>
> 1. FANOUT
>
>    [image]
> 2. XOR/CNOT
>
>    [image]
>
> We also need to recognize that the Fredkin map can be equivalently written as
>
> $$\mathrm{Fred}(x,y,z)= (x, x(y\oplus z)\oplus y, x(y\oplus z)\oplus z)$$
>
> This can be intuitively seen by noticing that if the control bit x is not set, the outputs are unchanged. If x is set, the outputs are swapped using the fabled
>   [XOR swap trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm). Combining these results, we write the complete circuit (with relevant intermediary ouputs labeled):
>
> [image]

Comment: But you can construct a Fredkin gate from three Toffoli gates

Answer (score 0):

Generally the way you prove something is minimal is by 1) enumerating all possible smaller configurations, or 2) looking at it in terms of a finite set of states, and showing that nothing smaller could hold the necessary number of states.

Comment: And you can often reduce the search space by proving any solutions must at least take on (or not take on) some set of forms.